# How do you underline text in an iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, ios4, underline

How to under line text in iphone(objective c)???

Comment: What text? In a UILabel? In a UITextField? In a UITextView? When drawing directly on a view? This is just not a question that anyone can answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple underlining for UILabel. So there are two approaches:

1. Using `UIWebView` where you can underline text you need with `<span style="text-decoration:underline">underlined html text<span>`.
2. Custom `UILabel` - this is a good idea for  short single-lined labels. You should create some `CUILabel` class that inherits `UILabel` and replace it's `drawRect` method in `@implementation` section with the following code:

`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0f/255.0f, 0.0f/255.0f, 255.0f/255.0f, 1.0f); // Your underline color
  CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0f);

  UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
  CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT);
  CGSize labelSize;
  labelSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  

  CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, self.bounds.size.height - 1);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, labelSize.width + 10, self.bounds.size.height - 1);

  CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

  [super drawRect:rect];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to NR4TR's answer another option would be to use CoreText.

Answer (score 0):

I changed NR4TR's code to be more automatic:

```
#import "UILabelUnderlined.h"

@implementation UILabelUnderlined

@synthesize underlineWidth;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.underlineWidth = 1.0f;
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGFloat red;
CGFloat green;
CGFloat blue;
CGFloat alpha;
[self.textColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, red, green, blue, 1.0f); // Your underline color
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, self.underlineWidth);

CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize;
labelSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  

CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 10, self.bounds.size.height - 1);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, labelSize.width + 10, self.bounds.size.height - 1);

CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

[super drawRect:rect];  
}

@end
```

Comment: Was discarding the alpha value from the text colour intentional?

Answer (score 0):

you can use webview & check mark "links" checkbox in Detection & give html text

```
    htmlContentTxt = @"<a title="XYZ" href="http://www.XYZ.com">www.XYZ.com</a>";
    [webview loadHTMLString:htmlContentTxt baseURL:nil];
```